# Polar decomposition of $A = E + \epsilon B$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition

I have encountered interesting problem:

So we have a real square matrix given as $A = E + \epsilon B$ which is very similar to the indentity matrix and the $\epsilon ^2$ we can neglect then.

And my textbook says the polar decomposition looks like:

$(E + \epsilon \frac {1}{2}(B-B^T))(E + \epsilon \frac {1}{2}(B+B^T))$

and I wasn't able to get there by myself. I don't understand why that result is true.

I tried singular decomposition first, calculating $AA^T$ and its eingenvalues, but I got pure nonsense.

The polar decomposition is defined as: $A = (U \Sigma U^T)(UV^T)$ where $U,V$ are the unitary matrices corresponding to the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ and $\Sigma $ has their square roots of the eigenvalues on its diagonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $E$ is your funny notation for the identity matrix $I$.

We have $A\equiv\exp(A-I)\pmod{\varepsilon^2}$.  Now decomposing $A-I$ into its symmetric and anti-symmetric components
$$
A-I=\underbrace{\frac{(A-I)+(A-I)^T}2}_{S}+\underbrace{\frac{(A-I)-(A-I)^T}2}_{T}=\varepsilon\frac{B+B^T}{2}+\varepsilon\frac{B-B^T}{2}
$$
and thus [Zassenhaus formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#The_Zassenhaus_formula) gives $\exp(A-I)=\exp(S+T)=\exp(S)\exp(T)\exp(-\frac12[S,T]+\dots)$.  Hence
$$
A\equiv\exp(S)\exp(T)\pmod{\varepsilon^2}
$$
which is your polar decomposition.

Comment: Yeah I forgot to rewrite it because in my country we call it an elementary matrix, translated. Haha.

Answer (score 2):

Given a real square matrix $A$ with positive determinant, its polar decomposition is given by $A=RU$, where $U$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix and $R$ is a properly orthogonal matrix.

The proof of the theorem shows that $U=\sqrt{A^TA}$ and $R=AU^{-1}$, so
$$
  U = \sqrt{A^TA} 
    = \sqrt{(E+\epsilon B)(E+\epsilon B^T)}
    \approx \sqrt{E+\epsilon(B+B^T)}
    \approx E+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon(B+B^T)
$$
and
$$
  R = AU^{-1} 
    \approx (E+\epsilon B)\left(E-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon(B+B^T)\right) 
    \approx E+\frac{1}{2}\epsilon(B-B^T) 
$$

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much for your answer.